# Is there a performance difference between looping RenderPartials and looping in the Partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**Which one of these will perform better:**

> On the parent page:
>
> ```
> foreach(var m in model)
> {
>    @Html.RenderPartial("PartialPage", m);
> }
> ```
>
> In the partial:
>
> ```
> <h2>@m.thang</h2>
> ```

**OR**

> On the parent page:
>
> ```
> @Html.RenderPartial("PartialPage", model);
> ```
>
> In the partial:
>
> ```
> foreach(var m in model)
> {
>  <h2>@m.thang</h2>
> }
> ```

For some reason unknown to me my gut tells me that the 2nd version would be better, but I have no basis for this.

Comment: Off the top of my head the first would be less performant given that you're "searching" for the partial page each time (minor hit).

Comment: @BuildStarted yes that is my impression as well, I'm hoping someone with some knowledge can confirm this

Comment: I like to think I'm pretty knowledgeable about Razor and MVC :)

Comment: @BuildStarted Ah, I thought since you posted as a comment instead of an answer that you weren't exactly sure.

Comment: Well, it was just the only thing I was aware of and it really wasn't answer worthy without doing a lot more like giving you alternatives and what not :)

Answer (score 0):

The first one will be a tad slower as you have the overhead of locating your partial view.
I don't think the difference will be noticeable.

Do organize your views with maintenance and reuse in mind - are you more likely to reuse a view for a single item or multiple items?

Also, with Display / Editor [templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) if you have a template for a single item you can still render the collection and MVC will invoke your template for each model. No need for manual looping.

Comment: Ooo... can you tell me more about these templates, maybe link me to a tutorial?

Comment: Just a side note that you can use ~ paths `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` and it results it slightly faster performance. Since it doesn't bother looking for the file in every location possible.

Comment: Added link to Brad Wilson's brilliant blog